# Agrupar por atributo común y presentar resultado en un campo separado x comas

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en Postgresql

| CodigoRutero | NumLinea | CodigoCliente | CodigoVendedor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 0023 | 0001 |
| 0002 | 1 | 0023 | 0002 |
| 0002 | 2 | 0001 | 0003 |
| 0003 | 1 | 0002 | 0003 |
| 0001 | 2 | 0002 | 0001 |

La idea es que la consulta me devuelva la informacion de esta manera:

| CodigoVendedor | Clientes |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0023,0002 |
| 0002 | 0023 |
| 0003 | 00010002 |

Alguna idea que me puedan brindar para lograrlo?

Gracias

Comment: Hola! Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio, recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los códigos de vendedor puedes usar la cláusula `group by`:

```
select CodigoVendedor
    from table1
    group by CodigoVendedor
    order by CodigoVendedor asc
```

esto devolverá todos los códigos sin repetir. Luego puedes usar las funciones de agregación [`array_to_string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html) y [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html): que convierten la columna `CodigoCliente` que ha sido "colapsada" por el `group by` en un arreglo y luego concatena sus elementos para formar la columna `Clientes`. La consulta quedaría:

```
select CodigoVendedor, array_to_string(array_agg(CodigoCliente), ',') as Clientes
from table1
group by CodigoVendedor
order by CodigoVendedor asc
```

puedes ver el [resultado acá](https://rextester.com/KGXS33960)